# How can I toggle individual <li> elements using only basic javascript and DOM manipulation to change their styling?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to toggle each item on a list to change its style through CSS, but I keep getting an error. Can someone explain what is wrong with my code?

HTML

```
    <button id="enter">Enter</button>
    <ul>
        <li>Notebook</li>
        <li>Apple</li>
        <li>Mango</li>
        <li>Banana</li>
        <li>BlackBerry</li>
        <li>Watermelon</li>
    </ul>
```

CSS

```
.change {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

Javascript

```
var li = document.querySelectorAll("li");

li.addEventListener("click" , function () {
    li.classList.toggle(".change");
})
```

Uncaught TypeError: li.addEventListener is not a function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to loop through all the elements using `forEach()`. And also remove `.` before change

```js
var li = document.querySelectorAll("li");

for(let i = 0;i<li.length;i++){
  li[i].addEventListener('click',function(){
    li[i].classList.toggle("change");
  })
}
```

```css
.change {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<button id="enter">Enter</button>
    <ul>
        <li>Notebook</li>
        <li>Apple</li>
        <li>Mango</li>
        <li>Banana</li>
        <li>BlackBerry</li>
        <li>Watermelon</li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: really good way to do it but i am still new and "this" is still hard to get it but what i understand "this" is li

Comment: @FahadMir `this` inside an event handler refers to element on which event is called. It means `this` will be this `<li>` element which is clicked.

Comment: i just to to replace "this" to "li" but get Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toggle' of undefined
    at HTMLLIElement.<anonymous> 

can you please wrote it in beginner javascript since i have not good idea about es6 also what does x mean ? i never seen x related stuff

Comment: @FahadMir `li` is collection of elements. Its not just one element. You need to loop through it. In the code `li[i]` repesents the single element. I have changed code to simple loops.